# Variables to get windows directories in x64 bit version?

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit

In x64 bit version of windows, i see that are also x86 bit directories. How do we get that using envirnoment variables ?

Comment: for what language? C#, C, C++, VB, Pascal? (etc.) You need to be more specific.

Comment: sorry for my bad english as native language is different

Comment: for vb, c# and also i need complete list of all variables

Comment: I don't think the language is relevant. I understood the question to ask about the common environment variables in Windows, which would work in any programming language or simply from a command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of recognized System Environment Variables in Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744%28WS.10%29.aspx)

- For, say, Program Files (x86), it's `PROGRAMFILES(X86)`
- Common Files under Program Files (x86) is `COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)`

Answer (score 1):

Which directory are you looking to find, specifically?

`PROGRAMFILES(X86)` refers to the C:\Program Files (x86) folder on 64-bit systems.

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744(WS.10).aspx